# Trying to make an Image Rotate (jQuery Animation) On Page Load to Specific Degree

Tags: jquery, image, animation, autorotate

I have an amplifier knob that I'd like to turn to a certain degree upon page load. I'm trying to use this jQuery library: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

I just don't know how to set it up properly. I was able to use the webkit to rotate the image, but I want there to be an animation. If anyone can let me know how to properly use the library I'd greatly appreciate it!

Remember, I need to have the rotation occur on page load. Ideally, the animation would repeat after 5-10 seconds. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: did you look at the example page?  http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Comment: yeah, I looked at the Example page, since I'm not a complete idiot. But I tried duplicating the examples and I couldn't get it to work. So I'm only partly an idiot. Thanks.

Comment: Your project is now working using ocergynohtnah's solution, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/eYdjW/

Comment: Should not need jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

everything is set up fine on tonesettings.com/rotate. the only issue you have is that you're calling the rotation() function before the page has completed loading. you can just move it into an on ready status and it should trigger on page load.

Change the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rotation = function (){
   $("#img").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation
   });
}
rotation();
</script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rotation = function (){
   $("#img").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation
   });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    rotation();
});
</script>
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: I think the asker abandoned his project since it's almost 1 year now. Too bad because your code is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/eYdjW/

Comment: 1 year later: Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can be here all day trying to guess your animation but here it is just play about with the values of the list below.

```
var rotation = function (){
   $("#img").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation,
      easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // 
          return c*(t/d)+b;
      }
   });
}
rotation();
```

- t: current time
- b: begInnIng value
- c: change In value
- d: duration

Comment: Okay I guess what I'm having most problem with is how to actually make this code work. Would you mind looking at the code and explain what I'm doing wrong? http://www.tonesettings.com/rotate/

Comment: you image has an id of "#img" remove the hash and try again, #in jequery just represents IDs of a html element, e.g. `<img id="test" />` would have `$('#test');` as a selector to say ur getting an element by id.

Comment: also only use one unique ID, or use the class attribute hit w3schools.com for tutorials and don't skip reading until u understand what they mean

Comment: Originally I added the id without the hash, since that's how I assumed it should work. I just changed it back to be without a # and it still doesn't work.. any ideas?

Comment: what error message do you get?, and have you checked that the rotate script has been injected b4 the rotation() function ?

Comment: I don't get any errors.. and yeah the rotate script is being injected.

Answer (score 0):

please check this for j query image rotating examples
 :

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples